# Export Mailchimp campaign into Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, html-email, mailchimp, gravity-forms-plugin

I've found Mailchimp's drag and drop features, clean html for emails, and mobile styling super helpful, so I'd like to essentially use Mailchimp as the design tool for Gravity Forms notification emails. I've got Gravity Forms loaded up on a Wordpress site. What's the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create your Mailchimp campaign and save it as a Template.
2. Navigate to the Template section and find the one you just saved.
3. Export it as HTML.
4. Run the exported HTML through [this tool](http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/) that creates inline CSS for you.
5. Replace all `px` `font-size` values with `pt`. (Sublime Text 2's regex: `font-size:(\d+)px` to `font-size:$1pt`)
6. Paste it into Gravity Forms' Message field, replacing any merge tags with GF's ones.
7. Ensure Auto-formatting is turned off under the Message field.

Comment: Hi Ian, this is useful - but why replace px values with pt ?

Comment: @JoannaMikalai Hm, I don't actually remember at this point. Might have been a quirk of Gravity Forms? In general, px make more sense than pt in a web environment…